# Using ImportXML to ID multiple tables

Tags: xml, google-sheets, import, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to fetch the data off this site from the table "Team Per 100 Poss Stats."

I'm using this :

Formula:= `ImportXml(A1, "//*[@id='div_team-stats-per_poss']")`

But I keep getting an error telling me the content is empty. How do I refer to that specific table? I checked the source code and the data *is* there.

https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2021.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(QUERY(
 ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTDATA(A1), 1300, 1), 
 "limit 30 offset 1159", 0), 
 "</?\S+[^<>]*>", "×"), "××"))
```

[image]

Comment: Could you explain why the XPath request does not work in this case?

Comment: @BorisBaublys its because the table is controled by JavaScript and google sheets cant imprt JS content. you can always test this if you disable JS for given site and after you refresh you can see whats left and thats what can be scraped

Comment: Yes, I just did it - I turned off the JS, reload the page and this table is missing.
Thank you. Could you explain your decision a little?

Comment: @BorisBaublys well if you run: `=ImportXml(A1, "//*")` you can see that required data are present but hard to get and hard to be formatted so we switch to IMPORTDATA to get a source code of that with html tags so after we trim it with ARRAY_CONSTRAIN (because whole source code is too big) and QUERY (to narrow it down a bit further) we use regex to replace all html tags with unique symbol so we can then use SPLIT to distribute values into multiple columns